D3 How to use FontAwesome icons
I would like to use the icon from FotnAwesome and append it to my g tag. As described here, I tried, but it doesn't work.
Does anyone have a hint?
I use d3.v7.js.


                             
            const svg = d3.select("#chart-area")
                        .append("svg") 
                            .attr("width", 800)  
                            .attr("height", 400) 
            
const g = d3.select("svg").append("g")
                            .attr('transform', `translate(10,20)`)

          g.append('text')
                        .attr('font-size', '12px')
                        .attr('font-family', 'FontAwesome')
                        .text('\uf118')
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/012613158b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="chart-area"></div>  




Have you included a reference to the FontAwesome source files somewhere else in your code?  Unless you load it into the page, the browser isn't going to magically make them appear. See https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/setup/get-started

Uff okay, how could I forget that. It works, thank you very much.
